# multiple matplotlib specgram with shared color bar

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have two specgram that I need to plot using the same color bar. I tried to follow previous posts, but I always get errors related to imshow or finding the min and the max between my two data set. 
Up to now, I am just using the colorbar for the dataset which probably will have the min and the max values (noisy data set)

```
NFFT = 1024
cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis')
cmap.set_under(color='k', alpha=None)

x=noisy.as_matrix()[:,1]
z=denoised [:,1]
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(20, 10))
values, ybins, xbins, im = ax1.specgram(x, NFFT=NFFT, cmap=cmap, 
Fs=128, noverlap=900)
ax1.set(title='original')

values1, ybins1, xbins1, im1 = ax2.specgram(z, NFFT=NFFT, cmap=cmap, 
Fs=128, noverlap=900)
ax2.set(title='deoised')
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax1)
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

my question is how to share the color map between the two specgrams and how to find the min and max?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [`mlab.specgram()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html?highlight=specgram#matplotlib.mlab.specgram) to get the spectral content of your signal *before* plotting it. Then you can find the min and max values across both spectra, and normalize your colorbar accordingly.

The following is not the most efficient code, since I am calculating the spectra twice, once with `mlab.specgram()` and the other with `Axes.specgram()` but it gets the job done. If you look at the code for [`Axes.specgram()`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/6044a571a373d62c2ef78ce977f9ff1ea131146a/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L7357), you could figure out how to plot the spectrogram without recalculating the spectra, but I did not take the time to figure it out.

signal data is from [specgram_demo](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/specgram_demo.html)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import mlab as mlab

dt = 0.0005
t = np.arange(0.0, 20.0, dt)
s1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*100*t)
s2 = 2*np.sin(2*np.pi*400*t)

# create a transient "chirp"
mask = np.where(np.logical_and(t > 10, t < 12), 1.0, 0.0)
s2 = s2 * mask

# add some noise into the mix
nse = 0.01*np.random.random(size=len(t))

x = s1 + s2 + nse  # the signal
z = x * 50
NFFT = 1024       # the length of the windowing segments
Fs = int(1.0/dt)  # the sampling frequency

spectrum1, freqs1, t1 = mlab.specgram(x, NFFT=NFFT, Fs=Fs, noverlap=900)
spectrum2, freqs2, t2 = mlab.specgram(z, NFFT=NFFT, Fs=Fs, noverlap=900)

min_val = 10 * np.log10(min(spectrum1.min(), spectrum2.min()))
max_val = 10 * np.log10(min(spectrum1.max(), spectrum2.max()))


gs0 = gs.GridSpec(2,2, width_ratios=[10,0.1])
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs0[0,0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs0[1,0])
cax = fig.add_subplot(gs0[:,1])
spectrum1, freqs1, t1, im1 = ax1.specgram(x, NFFT=NFFT, Fs=Fs, noverlap=900, cmap=cmap, vmin=min_val, vmax=max_val)
ax1.set(title='original')

spectrum2, freqs2, t2, im2 = ax2.specgram(z, NFFT=NFFT, Fs=Fs, noverlap=900, cmap=cmap, vmin=min_val, vmax=max_val)
ax2.set(title='denoised')
fig.colorbar(im1, cax=cax)

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to avoid this since I have thousands of plot to generate. What is the difference between  mlab.specgram() and Axes.specgram()?

Comment: `mlab.specgram()` does the calculation only, whereas `Axes.specgram()`does calculation+plotting. See [the code for `Axes.specgram()` on github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/6044a571a373d62c2ef78ce977f9ff1ea131146a/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L7357) to figure out how they plot the result of the calculation by  `mlab.specgram()`